# Magento 1.3 or 1.4

Tags: magento

I am having some real issues with Magento version 1.4, I get alot of "There has been an error processing your request." errors do you think going to the latest version of 1.3 would be more stable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, based on the information you've given, there's no reason 1.3 or 1.4 will run any more, or less stable for you.  Track down the reasons for the error message (in your PHP/Apache/Magento error log.  Once you know why the application is failing, you'll have a better idea if it's something specific to 1.4, or something about your general server setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with Alan on this one, that is if your question is only if 1.3 (1.3.3) is more stable than 1.4.  Since 1.3 has been around a lot longer, hand multiple sub-releases, etc., I think you'll find more stability in 1.3.3 than you would with 1.4.

If your question was whether or not to go with 1.3 or 1.4, I would definitely suggest going with 1.4.  You may want to tackle whatever might be causing your errors, as it could be something rather simple.  I have been using 1.4 since it came out, and developing pretty heavily with it, and I don't think I've gotten the error you are getting at all.  In fact, I don't think I have had any issues whatsoever.  There are known issues in upgrading to 1.4, but other than that, I have enjoyed it quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

The best to do would be to look at the error reports in var/reports/ and look at the exact error. That's not really a question of stablelity between the two versions.